# Why must we explicitly pass constants into multiprocessing functions?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been working with the `multiprocessing` package to speed up some geoprocessing (GIS/`arcpy`) tasks that are redundant and need to be done the same for more than 2,000 similar geometries.

The splitting up works well, but my "worker" function is rather long and complicated because the task itself from start to finish is complicated. I would love to break the steps apart down more but I am having trouble passing information to/from the worker function because for some reason ANYTHING that a worker function under multiprocessing uses needs to be passed in explicitly.

This means I cannot define constants in the body of `if __name__ == '__main__'` and then use them in the worker function. It also means that my parameter list for the worker function is getting really long - which is super ugly since trying to use more than one parameter also requires creating a helper "star" function and then `itertools` to rezip them back up (a la the second answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)).

I have created a trivial example below that demonstrates what I am talking about. Are there any workarounds for this - a different approach I should be using - or can someone at least explain **why** this is the way it is?

Note: I am running this on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64.

**Edit:** I seem to have not made my question clear enough. I am not that concerned with how `pool.map` only takes one argument (although it is annoying) but rather I do not understand why the scope of a function defined outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'` cannot access things defined inside that block *if it is used as a multiprocessing function* - unless you explicitly pass it as an argument, which is obnoxious.

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import itertools

def loop_function(word):
    file_name = os.path.join(root_dir, word + '.txt')
    with open(file_name, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(word + " food")

def nonloop_function(word, root_dir): # <------ PROBLEM
    file_name = os.path.join(root_dir, word + '.txt')
    with open(file_name, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(word + " food")

def nonloop_star(arg_package):
     return nonloop_function(*arg_package)

# Serial version
#
# if __name__ == '__main__':
# root_dir = 'C:\\hbrowning'
# word_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'llama', 'yeti', 'parakeet', 'dolphin']
# for word in word_list:
#     loop_function(word)
#
## --------------------------------------------

# Multiprocessing version
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_dir = 'C:\\hbrowning'
    word_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'llama', 'yeti', 'parakeet', 'dolphin']
    NUM_CORES = 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_CORES, maxtasksperchild=1)

    results = pool.map(nonloop_star, itertools.izip(word_list, itertools.repeat(root_dir)),
                   chunksize=1)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to define them in the `__name__` block rather than at module level, which would work.

Comment: Actually, defining things in the block works fine for me as well. Why do you think you need to zip everything up?

Comment: Because `pool.map` for Python 2.7 only takes a function and one argument (again, from the question I linked). I am confused about why things are working for you - perhaps you could post some code that worked?

Comment: And I get `NameError: global name 'root_dir' not defined` if I run the `loop_function` with a single argument (word_list) under multiprocessing

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Windows behaves differently, since it doesn't have `fork`. HFBrowning is probably on Windows, and you're probably not.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112 - I forgot that would be important. I'll edit

Comment: Ah good point. Actually, I am on Windows right now, but using the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, at least on Windows (although there are similar caveats with *nix `fork` style of multiprocessing, too) that, when you execute your script, it (to greatly simplify it) effectively ends up as as if you called two blank (shell) processes with `subprocess.Popen()` and then have them execute:

```
python -c "from your_script import nonloop_star; nonloop_star(('dog', 'C:\\hbrowning'))"
python -c "from your_script import nonloop_star; nonloop_star(('cat', 'C:\\hbrowning'))"
python -c "from your_script import nonloop_star; nonloop_star(('yeti', 'C:\\hbrowning'))"
python -c "from your_script import nonloop_star; nonloop_star(('parakeet', 'C:\\hbrowning'))"
python -c "from your_script import nonloop_star; nonloop_star(('dolphin', 'C:\\hbrowning'))"
```

one by one as soon as one of those processes finishes with the previous call. That means that your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block never gets executed (because it's not the main script, it's imported as a module) so anything declared within it is not readily available to the function (as it was never evaluated).

For the staff outside your function you can at least cheat by accessing your `module` via `sys.modules["your_script"]` or even with `globals()`  but that works only for the evaluated staff, so anything that was placed within the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard is not available as it didn't even had a chance. That's also a reason why you must use this guard on Windows -  without it you'd be executing your pool creation, and other code that you nested within the guard, over and over again with each spawned process.

If you need to share read-only data in your multiprocessing functions, just define it in the global namespace of your script, outside of that `__main__` guard, and all functions will have the access to it (as it gets re-evaluated when starting a new process) regardless if they are running as separate processes or not.

If you need data that changes then you need to use something that can synchronize itself over different processes - there is a slew of modules designed for that, but most of the time Python's own pickle-based, datagram communicating `multiprocessing.Manager` (and types it provides), albeit slow and not very flexible, is enough.

Comment: This is a great answer, @zwer! I didn't explain but my reasoning for not wanting to include the data in the module level environment is that it is expensive to calculate (3 hours) and I only need it done once per script run. Then I make 2,000 reports in a parallel way, hitting off the same data. It sounds like splitting these into two scripts and using the data paths as constants in the latter would be a clearer approach. But at least I understand the program execution flow now - something I could not grasp based on the documentation.

Comment: @HFBrowning - if it takes a long time to evaluate your data (assuming large quantities) and your processes need unrestricted access to the whole data set - I'd recommend you store it in some in-memory database ([`Redis`](https://redis.io/) for example) then have your processes poll the data from it. If the processes can use the data in a serialized way (so no need for the whole set at once), you can create a streaming dispatcher pattern like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502827/7553525) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415368/7553525) and feed your workers in a controlled manner.

Comment: I've never heard of `Redis` before - it looks great! Thank you for the additional suggestions (:

Answer (score 0):

> Python » 3.6.1 Documentation: [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)
>
> ```
> map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though)
> ```

There is no Restriction, only it have to be a iterable!
Try a `class Container`, for instance:

```
class WP(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.root_dir ='C:\\hbrowning'
        self.name = name

word_list = [WP('dog'), WP('cat'), WP('llama'), WP('yeti'), WP('parakeet'), WP('dolphin')]
results = pool.map(nonloop_star, word_list, chunksize=1)
```

> **Note**: The `Var Types` inside the `class` have to be `pickleable`!
>   Read about [what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)