# Share object state across processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In the code below, how do I make the `Starter` object be able to read `gen.vals`?
It seems like a different object gets created, whose state gets updated, but `Starter` never knows about it. Also, how would the solution apply for `self.vals` being a dictionary, or any other kind of object?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Generator(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = []
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.vals.append(i)
            print 'In Generator ', self.vals # prints growing list
            i += 1

class Starter():
    def do_stuff(self):
        gen = Generator()
        gen.start()
        while True:
            print 'In Starter ', gen.vals # prints empty list
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starter = Starter()
    starter.do_stuff()
```

Output:

```
In Starter  []
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
In Starter  []
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. Section 16.6.1.4

Comment: Would you care to demonstrate a solution to the example? It's a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example, so it shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a process it essentially executes in a whole separate context (here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572749/7553525) on what's going on) so there is no shared memory to speak of, therefore whatever your `run()` method does doesn't really reflect in your main process - Python spawns/forks a whole new process out of it, instantiates your `Generator` there and calls its `run()` method and any changes to the state of that other instance in a different process stay there.

If you want to pass data around, you need to use some multiprocessing aware structures that will essentially serialize/deserialize data between different processes and communicate the changes back and forward. For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Generator(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self._vals = []  # keeps the internal state
        self.vals = multiprocessing.Queue()  # a queue for the exchange
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self._vals.append(i)  # update the internal state
            print('In Generator ', self._vals) # prints growing list
            self.vals.put(self._vals)  # add it to the queue
            i += 1

class Starter():
    def do_stuff(self):
        gen = Generator()
        gen.start()
        while True:
            print('In Starter ', gen.vals.get()) # print what's in the queue
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starter = Starter()
    starter.do_stuff()
```

Will print out:

```
In Generator  [0]
In Starter  [0]
In Generator  [0, 1]
In Starter  [0, 1]
In Generator  [0, 1, 2]
In Starter  [0, 1, 2]
In Generator  [0, 1, 2, 3]
In Starter  [0, 1, 2, 3]
etc.
```

If you want to do more complex/semi-concurrent data modifications or deal with more structured data, check the structures supported by [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). Of course, for very complex stuff I'd always recommend using an in-memory database like [Redis](https://redis.io) as a means of inter-process data exchange. Or, if you prefer to do micro-management yourself, [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/) is always a good option.

Comment: Or in other words, why is your solution not good for more structured data?

Comment: @BaronYugovich - it will work for any structure, as long as it can be pickled as that's how Python's multiprocessing-aware structures communicate.

Comment: So why do you say "If you want to do more complex/semi-concurrent data modifications or deal with more structured data, ...", for which cases is this solution a problem?

Comment: @BaronYugovich - it's not good for complex data because sometimes it cannot be pickled, and in other instances you just want to communicate the changes, not to constantly pickle/unpickle your whole objects. `multiprocessing.Manager` has some optimizations when it communicates changes instead of blindly pickling/unpickling objects, but for really large and complex data you'll be much better off relying on something designed for complex inter-process communication from the ground up. In other words, try passing 100M element list this way and you'll see what I'm talking about.