# python (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a python game script and I wanted to know how to make my code run simultaniously with multiprocessing, I have this following code and basically what I have is my `def moving_on` function looping every 2 seconds and then I'll use another function `def test(self)` to check something in the game every 2 hours, that's why I need to use multiprocessing since the first `def`function cannot wait 2 hours to loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from login import username, password, cronometer, energy, no_energy
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import logging

class gameBot:
   def __init__(self, username, password):
        (basically logs into the game with username and password)

   def moving_on(self, cronometer, energy, no_energy):
        (checks if its able to refill energy and refills automatically)
   
   def test(self)
       logging.info("multiprocessing is working...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot=gameBot(username, password)
    p1 = Process(target=bot.moving_on, args=(cronometer, energy, no_energy))
    p2 = Process(target=bot.test)
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

if I run the script normally, **without** multiprocessing, simply by writing this at the bottom:

```
bot=gameBot(username, password)
bot.moving_on(cronometer, energy, no_energy)
```

then it works fine, but like I explained that's not what I need.

and if I run the script **using** (or at least trying to) the multiprocessing method like shown on the first code above, it logs into the game site with username and password, goes to the main page but then gives me an error on `p1.start()`, error: (`Exception has occurred: EOFError Ran out of input`)

Comment: Are you trying to get some input in moving_on? Check your code.

Comment: no input in moving_on

Comment: Well something is happening in the context of moving_on that causes the crash. You will need to look at the stack trace.

Comment: This sound like you want multi-threading instead of multi-processing.

Comment: ok I'll have a look at it, thank you

Comment: Without knowing more fully what `moving_on` does (is it CPU intensive or not), I wouldn't know whether threading would be more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EOFError: Ran out of input inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704086/eoferror-ran-out-of-input-inside-a-class)